# WiX: can I change the size or position of controls in the Standard Dialogs?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've increased the size of some fonts in the WiX Standard Dialogs, now some of the text overflows or doesn't fit. Can I adjust the size and position of some controls, without writing a custom dialog, or messing with the WiX source?

Here is my naïve attempt:

```
<Product>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <UI>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg"
            Control="Description"
            Property="Height">
            30
        </Publish>
    </UI>
</Product>
```

Of course it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes! Brilliant! Thank you! I had seen your blog, but search led me to the "L10N/M10N: Localization minimization" topic. The correct version of above becomes: `<UI Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Description" Height="30" />` in the .WXL file. Makes sense, as the dimensions will vary depending on the language.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way is to use [localization support to override control locations and sizes in WiX v3.6](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2012/07/14/localizing-more-than-strings-in-wix-v3-6/).

Comment: (Sorry, my comment above was meant for this post, not the original post).